# Why use acronyms at the beginning of a resource ID?

Tags: api, design-patterns, stripe-payments, finance

Why are some financial APIs using acronyms at the beginning of a resource ID? Is there a specific reason? Avoid coalition of ID's?

And, is it possible to have a coalition of V4 UUIDs in short mode? How to avoid?

**PS1**: Example of IDs with acronyms at the beginning: `card_1HHTFf2eZvKYlo2Cfk8wcBwa`, `tok_1HHTFg2eZvKYlo2CJyMFQfnf` in [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards) and `acc_1234567890cc` in [Yapily API](https://docs.yapily.com/?version=latest#19909d3a-0d5c-4e06-b97e-0d779df3b49d).

**PS2**: I use the NPM [short-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-uuid) package so that the V4 UUIDs are in short mode.

Answer (score 2):

At Stripe, this is purely for the human looking at the ID's benefit. You can quickly identify whether the ID you're looking at represents a token (tok_123) or an account (acct_123) without having to look up more details. If all the IDs were pure UUIDs this wouldn't be possible.

The prefixes are especially useful when debugging.